# SASS Mixin in Rails error Invalid CSS after "...x: #{}-": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was ";"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

This code is throwing the error...

> Invalid CSS after "...x: #{$prefix}-": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was ";"

```
@mixin rules-responsive($prefix, $medias, $postfix) {
  @if ($prefix != '' and $prefix != null) {
   $prefix: #{$prefix}-;
  }

@each $resolution, $alias in $medias {
  @if ($resolution == 0) {
    @each $offset in $offsets {
    .#{$prefix}#{$postfix} {
      @content;
    }
  }
} @else {
  @media (min-width: $resolution) {
    @each $offset in $offsets {
      .#{$prefix}#{$alias}-#{$postfix} {
        @content;
       }
      }
     }
    }
   }
  }
```

The code looks simple enough.. If $prefix is not null then append a "-" to the end of it. It appears the - is being treated as an operator, not a string. If I replace the - with foo, no error. Enclosing the '-' in quotes creates errors further along in the code

> Invalid CSS after ".hrleft": expected selector, was ""-"0"

I'm not sure why I cant just move the "-" down to the IF statement below like it is after #{$alias}

```
.#{$prefix}-#{$postfix} {
```

There must be a reason why the template coder did it this way but I haven't tested it enough to find out why.

What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use double quotes for the whole expression (tested with sass-3.5.1):

```
@mixin rules-responsive($prefix, $medias, $postfix) {
  @if ($prefix != '' and $prefix != null) {
   $prefix: "#{$prefix}-";
  }
```